# different (not all) .NET programs quietly fail on windows 7 ultimate

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework

For some time now,  I have trouble running different programs on my windows 7 x64 ultimate pc. Most importantly right now: mRemoteNG. They do not start at all. No process can be found in the task manager, no output if i start from windows console, and no entries in the event manager. Do .net programs log somewhere else?

Unfortunately, there isn't much more info, maybe somebody has an idea where to look , or just a direction?

Already reinstalled the programs, and also tried repairing and reinstalling the net-framework. No change

All help appreciated!

Comment: What versions of the .NET Framework do you have installed? What version does nRemoteNG require?  There can be a log but only if they program creates it.

Comment: it requires Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 or Higher, I have 4.5 installed. no files are written in the program folder, as far as i can see. to be clear: the install DOES work, it is just not running!

Comment: What version of `nRemoteNG` are you trying exactly? Are all of the required services and plugins are already installed and/or working? The fact the program does not run at all tells me its missing a required dependency.  This means the program isn't even getting to the point where it can generate an error log.

Comment: I tried a bunch of versions, most recently the newest 1.72. AS far as i can tell from the site, there are no requrements besides the net framework.  everything else is optional or am I wrong?

Comment: They are actually required.

Comment: thanks for your help! I installed the citrix online plugin. xulrunner is not an installable appliction (mremoteng just needs the path to the exe), and terminal service client is included from windwos 7 on, if I am not mistaken. unfortunalety no change :(

Comment: Once you have 20 reputation you should take this to `Root Access` chatroom.